# Why is Wordpress not recognising the function I created?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I am trying to create a function with two variables. One variable is the text I want to hover over, the other variable is the text I want displayed when I hover over the first text mentioned. I'm using the following shortcode from Shortcodes Ultimate to create this function:

```
[su_tooltip style="yellow" position="top" shadow="no" rounded="no" size="default" title="" content="Tooltip text" behavior="hover" close="no" class=""]Hover me to open tooltip[/su_tooltip]
```

I have written the following function in functioins.php:

```
function hov($x, $y)
{
    echo "[su_tooltip style= \"yellow\" 
     position=\"top\" 
     shadow=\"no\" 
     rounded=\"no\" 
     size=\"default\" 
     title=\"\" 
     content =strval($y) 
     behavior=\"hover\" 
     close=\"no\" 
     class=\"\"]$x'[/su_tooltip)]'";
}
```

I added the backslash so the code ignores the quotes.
I saved this function. I tried running this function in a text editor page as follows:

```
hov(arg1,arg2)
```

But it just published "hov(arg1,arg2)" as a literal string.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to type `hov('foo', 'bar');` into your `HTML` then it will output that as text.

To call a `PHP` function from inside your template you need the opening and closing `PHP` tags.

So in your templates, to call this function you would use the following code.

```php
<?php hov('foo', 'bar'); ?>
```

If you're trying to call for a `shortcode` then you need to use `echo do_shortcode(['...']);`

```php
<?php echo do_shortcode(hov('foo', 'bar')); ?>
```

**Revised Answer**

To run a `PHP` function by calling it in the post editor you need to create a `shortcode`

Shortcodes are created by using the WordPress function `add_shortcode`
See: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/

```php
add_shortcode('hov', 'hov'); // create ['hov'] which calls hov()
function hov($args = [])
{
    return do_shortcode(sprintf('[su_tooltip style="yellow" position="top" shadow="no" rounded="no" size="default" title="" content="%s" behavior="hover" close="no" class=""]%s[/su_tooltip]', $args['y'], $args['x']));
}
```

Example usage

`[hov y="foo" x="bar"]` Where `x` and `y` are passed as items inside of `$args`

Comment: Thanks for responding. When I call the function with the opening and closing tags in the text editor, nothing appears when I publish it.  Why is this?

Comment: Ahh your trying in the post editor. You cannot run `PHP` inside the post editor, ill update my answer you show you how to create a shortcode out of your function

Comment: Thanks the definitely looks cleaner. I have the following in my functions.php: add_shortcode('hov', 'hov'); // create ['hov'] which calls hov()
'function hov($args = [])
{
    return "[su_tooltip style= \"yellow\" 
     position=\"top\" 
     shadow=\"no\" 
     rounded=\"no\" 
     size=\"default\" 
     title=\"\" 
     content =strval({$args['y']}) 
     behavior=\"hover\" 
     close=\"no\" 
     class=\"\"]{$args['x']}[/su_tooltip]";
}' and I have the following on my page text editor: '[hov y="foo" x="bar"]'. It's coming back blank though when I publish.

Comment: It's probably the the \ have been added, ill add it back to answer.

Comment: Updated the new shortcode to call `do_shortcode` on the old shortcode! Tested it, and works. p.s. you can change `x` and `y` to something more relevant to what that shortcode outputs.

Comment: When you say you paste this in a text editor, do you just create a random php file, like test.php that only contains <?php hov('foo', 'bar'); ?>? Are you linking to any Wordpress files before you try to use the function?

Comment: No, that would be inside `single.php` or `archive.php` for example. I was more trying to say, `not` in the post editor

Comment: Oh because it's telling there's a syntax error when I run that without the /. It makes sense to use sprintf and I thought that would take care of it. I also tried swapping double quotes for single quotes. Strange that it's working for you though,, could it be that I'm doing this in functions.php?

Comment: That was my bad again sorry, I left the closing `?>` from my my code in there. If you remove that, it shouldn't break anything.